# Apache can't be accessed externally

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, mysql

I have Ubuntu server with pre-installed apache2, mssql, php5. I install vTiger CRM and it's available on my localhost and internal IP.

But i can't reach it using my external IP. I checked all setups on my router and it seems to be ok.

This is my **netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN**

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 10.1.0.4:16001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29131         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0d:3a:b3:0e:a1  
          inet addr:10.1.0.4  Bcast:10.1.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20d:3aff:feb3:ea1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16493 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10379793 (10.3 MB)  TX bytes:7676670 (7.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:208812 (208.8 KB)  TX bytes:208812 (208.8 KB)
```

**apache2 ports.conf**

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**tcpdump -i eth0 port 80**

```
19:08:55.678954 IP 10.1.0.4.36536 > 168.63.129.16.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 27278000 ecr 783042300], length 0
19:08:55.679007 IP 10.1.0.4.36536 > 168.63.129.16.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:204, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 27278000 ecr 783042300], length 203
19:08:55.729432 IP 168.63.129.16.http > 10.1.0.4.36536: Flags [.], ack 204, win 513, options [nop,nop,TS val 783042305 ecr 27278000], length 0
19:08:55.729458 IP 10.1.0.4.36536 > 168.63.129.16.http: Flags [P.], seq 204:646, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 27278013 ecr 783042305], length 442
19:08:55.731846 IP 168.63.129.16.http > 10.1.0.4.36536: Flags [P.], seq 1:188, ack 646, win 511, options [nop,nop,TS val 783042305 ecr 27278013], length 187
19:08:55.731878 IP 10.1.0.4.36536 > 168.63.129.16.http: Flags [.], ack 188, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 27278013 ecr 783042305], length 0
19:08:55.732685 IP 10.1.0.4.36536 > 168.63.129.16.http: Flags [F.], seq 646, ack 188, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 27278014 ecr 783042305], length 0
19:08:55.733574 IP 168.63.129.16.http > 10.1.0.4.36536: Flags [F.], seq 188, ack 647, win 511, options [nop,nop,TS val 783042306 ecr 27278014], length 0
19:08:55.733587 IP 10.1.0.4.36536 > 168.63.129.16.http: Flags [.], ack 189, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 27278014 ecr 783042306], length 0
19:09:20.850089 IP 10.1.0.4.36545 > 168.63.129.16.http: Flags [S], seq 718277970, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 27284293 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:09:20.850513 IP 168.63.129.16.http > 10.1.0.4.36545: Flags [S.], seq 228035263, ack 718277971, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,sackOK,TS val 783044817 ecr 27284293], length 0
```

**cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/vtiger.stuffex.com.ua.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin a.redko@stuffex.com.ua
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vtiger.stuffex.com.ua/
  ServerName vtiger.stuffex.com.ua
  ServerAlias www.vtiger.stuffex.com.ua
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
  <Directory /var/www/html/vtiger.stuffex.com.ua/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.stuffex.com.ua-error_log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.status.com.ua-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName vtiger.stuffex.com.ua
   Redirect permanent / https://vtiger.stuffex.com.ua/
</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd.conf**

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1. use tcpdump to make sure, requests to the public ip are actually arriving on the linux box: `tcpdump -i eth0 port 80`
 1. check if your virtual hosts are using either wildcards (name based virtual hosts) or the real external ip address
 1. if this does not lead to the solution, please provide:
   * a (probably anonymised) version of your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` which are symlinked from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`
   * corresponding log entries from `/var/log/apache2/`

Comment: hi, i add /etc/apache2/sites-available/ (it linked with /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/) to my post. My cat vtiger.stuffex.com.ua-error_log is empty

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you change your vhost to name based:

- Replace the IP address with *:443 and add ssl certificates
- set the server name to your alias minus the www.
- add a second vhost for http which only redirects to https

This should allow you to use vtiger from the local network and from the outside world and has added security through https.

Now let's see, why your present config did not work:

- tcpdump states two IP addresses `10.1.0.4` and `168.63.129.16` - the latter seems to be your external IP address, whereas the first is the internal (is that right?)
- your vhost tells the httpd to ONLY answer requests that are aimed at `52.178.222.227`
- most probably all logging went to `/var/log/apache2/(access|error)?log`

The httpd could not find a suitable vhost for the requests (you probably removed the default?) and rejected all requests.

Comment: Hi Phillip, thank you so much for so detailed answer. I configure vtiger.stuffex.com.ua.conf as you said: replace port 443 and new vhost for redirecting http to https. (see my update into the initial post) is it right?

Comment: Exactly, my internal ip is 10.1.0.4, external seems to be 168.63.129.16 but my azure cloud says me that 52.178.222.227 is my external ip. i'm confused

Comment: also i add my httpd.conf into initial post

Comment: Not sure what Microsoft does with their azure thingy, but that looks as if it was a nat gateway. Anyway: name based vhosts should work around that problem of yours.

Comment: but it still doesn't work :(